# Im using bootstrap but still not flex

Tags: html, css, frontend

here is my `index.html`:

```
    <div id="container1" class="py-0 my-0">
        <div id="left" class="col-md-6">
            <img class="image" src="C:\Users\asus\Desktop\project\image.png">
        </div>

            <div id="right" class="col-md-6">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-index">
                            <a href="./index.html" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-index">
                            <a href="./pages/aboutUs.html" class="nav-link">ABOUT US</a>
                        </li>
                                        
                        <li class="nav-index">
                            <a href="./pages/courses.html" class="nav-link">COURSES</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-index">
                            <a href="./pages/login.html" class="nav-link">LOG IN</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
            <p class="paragraph col-md-6">
                <h3 class="Welcome text-center">Welcome to mobile legends!</h3>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
<br>
<br>
            <footer class="footer1" id="footer1">
                <h6>Contact the developer:</h6>
                <p>luckyllemos0909@gmail.com</p>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is my `style.css`:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#container1{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

#left {
  background: #ffd6dd;
  align-items: center;
}
.image{
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  padding: 100px;
}
#right {
  background: #FBAED2;
  align-items: center;
}

.paragraph{
  color: red;
  margin: 50px;
}

.fa {
  margin-top: none;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 2px;
}
.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.fa-facebook {
  color: #000000;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  color: #000000;
}

.fa-youtube {
  color: #000000;
}

.Welcome{
  margin-left:60px;
}

.nav-link{
  color: #000000;
}
.nav-index{
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

my problem is when i put it in mobile phone it does not go flexible.
This is the original output: [image]
and This what happens when try to look on mobile screen:[image]

Comment: just using bootstrap does not make your website responsive. bootstrap just provides some classes to make it easier

Comment: Did you try [reading the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is media queries, which let you decide how your website looks on varying screen sizes. In the example below in the css class example is first shown how it would look on a larger screen size, then below with the media query in effect you can stylize how your page would look on a (in this example) a screen with a width of less than 900px. Take a look at the link below for further explanation.

```
.example {
  font-family: "Droid+Sans";
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff ;
  font-size: 7rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17%;
  width: 100%;
}

    @media screen and (max-width: 900px){

  .example {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 100px;   
  }
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use `Bootstrap Utility Classes` in a better way. Since you are using bootstrap simply add your classes to work for different break points.

Add `col-12` Utility classes on the following elements: Note that Bootstrap follows `mobile-first` approach.

```
 <div id="left" class="col-12 col-md-6">
```

And

```
<div id="right" class="col-12 col-md-6">
```